# What response code should an API return for a value that was updated but not changed?

Tags: rest, api, error-handling, server, api-design

Is there a typically agreed upon response code for an API call that does not actually update data? For example, a text field is currently 'blah' and user hits 'edit' and 'save', should the API return 200 even if nothing was changed from its previous value?

It seems if it were to send a 2xx response the only way to let a user know nothing was updated, or to not send an API call in the first place, would be to completely manage the state in frontend, and then allow that call to go through only if nothing was changed? Or would it be appropriate to just have the backend throw a 4xx since the data is not really valid since it is was the same as before?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are achieving. If you want the value to be updated, you can handle it with a proper status code. And if the value updates alright and it's not updating in the database, you also handle with a status code to know why it's not being updated in the database. 
You can do something like this:

```
    [Route("PutData")]
     public HttpResponseMessage PutData(model obj)
     {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                model newobj = new model();

                newobj.a = obj.a;
                newobj.b = obj.b;

                DBContex context = new DBContex();

                context.ProcName(newobj.a, newobj.b);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex);
            }

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
        }
    }
```

I hope you understand what i put in my code. when the model state is valid go through the code else return 400 (Bad Request). When it's valid and there is an error the status code will return 500 and the error will be shown to you at the backend else(if no error) then 204 which is modified.
Now if you want to perform an update in API without updated the table, it's better you go for a stored procedure and just call it in the simplest way.
I hope i replied to your question